# XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2f78, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002f78 in IE and net::ERR_UNEXPECTED in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In our application we are facing one issue.
In my local eclipse whole application is working fine.
But in Prod server we are facing this issue-When I want to load one page it is throwing error. The problem is that we are getting different errors in both IE and Chrome.

In chrome we are getting below error[image]

In IE we are getting below error
[image]

I tried to fix IE error by adding something like below code

```
$.ajax({
url:url,
type:"POST",
data:data,
contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType:"json",
success: function(){
  ...
}
});
```

But it is not working.
Please help.

Comment: Have you tried removing some params? Like `contentType`?

Comment: yes.But still it is not working. It is working fine in Local environment.

Comment: But in Prod and SIT environment it is throwing these errors

Comment: What does network tab requests shows?

Answer (score 4):

I was able to produce this issue/error on demand while testing server request timeout.

I set my local Glassfish 4.1 request timeout to 30 seconds and I created an ajax (POST) call that took over 60 seconds to complete.

I got the same error. I would recommend to check your server's "Request timeout" value and check how long your requests take in the Dev Tools (Network tab)>

My local instance of Glassfish 4.1:
[image]

Error displayed in the IE console:
[image]

Network tab in IE Dev Tools:
[image]

Hopefully, this be useful to further troubleshooting of your issue.

Answer (score 1):

XMLHttpRequest is not working at all when sending with GET methods and parameters which include accents (é,à,ç, ...). You have to use POST method to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling Https/2 resolved this issue

Some how IE 11 and Https/2 is not playing well in my case